# How to integrate PLC with flutter desktop app using Ethernet

Tags: flutter, dart, plc

As of right now I am working on an interesting project, which consists of integrating PLC controllers with flutter desktop app.
Does anyone have any prior knowledge of this type of integration?

Points I know.

1. Making flutter desktop app.
2. Working with scanners and some scanning hardwares.

Points I need help into.

1. Integrating PLC controller using ethernet protocol with flutter desktop app.
2. How to read and write into PLC controller.

I am thinking of trying socket and Modbus protocal for communicating.